# Wicket DataTable with grouping

Tags: datatable, header, wicket

I'm trying to make a `DataTable` in Wicket that has 'special' rows that implement grouping, or headers, in between data rows.

See for example here: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

What would be the best approach?

1. Add a group-header item in the `Provider`, and have all the columns have special rendering for if such an item is provided
2. Add a group-header item in the `Provider`, and have the `DataTable` generate a special `DataGrid` that does the magic
3. Write my own `DataTable` implementation that has a `getRowComponent()` that skips the `IColumns` all together
4. ...?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Wicket integration for DataTables: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/datatables-parent

There is an example project showing how to start. You just have pass the proper config and JSON data.

If you feel adventurous you may try to integrate with https://www.ag-grid.com/best-javascript-data-grid/. I think it is the more featureful grid out there.